# Why did Saki's cantus arrive late?

Tags: from-the-new-world

It's been long since I watched this, but as far as I can remember, Saki's cantus "arrived late". I think it was in the scene where her bedroom's things begun flying around violently while she slept.

When she arrives at the academy, she says something along the lines of

> Well, it's not so weird for somebody to get their cantus late, right?

But they tell her that nobody else got their cantus late. She was the only one.

Is it ever explained, perhaps in the novel, why did her cantus arrive late?

Comment: I haven't read the novel, but I don't think it would be explained. However, her Cantus arriving late can be explained by natural distribution and she is an outlier on the distribution.

Answer (score 1):

It was implied that one gains cantus with the onset of puberty*. My explanation is that Saki got into puberty a bit later than the others.

*: I've read or heard this somewhere, but can't find a good link.